# Outlook API: Search mail

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to search the outlook v2 API for a message containing a URL.

The html body of the message contains a URL:

```
<a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">http://www.google.com</a>
```

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$search=%22http://www.google.com%22

- Returns no results

%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%22

- Returns no results

%22http%3a%2f%2fwww*google*com%22

- Returns the mail
- Also returns the message containing `<a href=\"http://www.google.co.uk/\">http://www.google.co.uk</a>, good company.`

Is there any way to query without wildcards that will return only messages with the exact URL match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Outlook documentation, the Body of a messages is not filterable, so you won't be able to search it for content.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#message.

Answer (score 0):

You can Microsoft Search API for filtering emails.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages